# qtip2 - Click Event not working on first click

Tags: jquery, qtip, qtip2

I have something weird that is happening and I was hoping someone can shed some light on it for me. 
I am using the qtip2 plugin on an  element on the page. Here is the code for it:

```
$('.tooltipEdit').click(function(){
var id = $(this).attr('id');
$(this).qtip({  
     show:{
         event: 'click',
                 solo: true
    },
    content: {
            text:'<form id="tooltipForm"><input type="text" value="'+$(this).text()+'" />  <button id="tooltipSave">Save</button></form>'
    },
    position : {
        my : 'top center',
        at: 'bottom center',
        target: $('#'+id+'')
    },
    hide: {
        delay : 500,
        fixed: true
    },
    style: {
        classes: 'ui-tooltip-blue ui-tooltip-shadow ui-tooltip-rounded'
    },
        events: {
            show: function(event, api) {
                $('#tooltipSave').click(function()
                {
                    var contact = 0;
                                            if($('#'+id+'').attr('id') == 'callFromContactName')
                    {
                        contact = $('#contactFromId').val();
                    }

                    if($('#'+id+'').attr('id') == 'callToContactName')
                    {
                        contact = $('#contactToId').val();
                    }

                    $.ajax(
                    {
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "php/myurl.php",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: 'callid='+$('#callid').val()+'&field='+$('#'+id+'').attr('id')+'&value='+encodeURIComponent($('#tooltipForm input').val())+'&contact='+contact,
                        success: function(j) 
                        {
                            return true;
                        },
                        error: function()
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                    });

                    return false;
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

As you can see I am creating a form within the tooltip with a "save button to submit back to the server.

I have seen two things that are strange.

1) When I click on the element with that class, the first click does nothing but then the second time I click on it the tooltip shows up. Why is it not coming up on the first click?

2) There are times when the wrong text is in showing inside the form within the tooltip. If I am using a dynamic population of the form, why would it not be the correct text all the time?

I have read about using jquery's destroy() method for pages with multiple tooltips and I bet that would help but I do not know where to use it.

All help would be appreciated!

UPDATE: You cna see the code in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DULDx/1/
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be applying the qtip plugin in an each statement.  Change the click to each.  Also to fix the form data you need to reference this before the qtip call.  Prior to using the plugin on your element you need to get a reference to `this` otherwise the qtip event when you use `this` will be referencing something different.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/PqyFj/1/

```
$('.tooltipEdit').each(function(){
var id = $(this).attr('id');
var $this = $(this);  // get a reference so we can use it in the show event of qtip
$(this).qtip({  
     show:{
         event: 'click',
                 solo: true
    },
    content: {
            text:'<form id="tooltipForm"><input type="text" value="'+$this.text()+'" />  <button id="tooltipSave">Save</button></form>'  // we use $this now to reference the element that was outside qtip
    },
    position : {
        my : 'top center',
        at: 'bottom center',
        target: $('#'+id+'')
    },
    hide: {
        delay : 500,
        fixed: true
    },
    style: {
        classes: 'ui-tooltip-blue ui-tooltip-shadow ui-tooltip-rounded'
    },
        events: {
            show: function(event, api) {
                $('#tooltipSave').click(function()
                {
                    var contact = 0;
                                            if($('#'+id+'').attr('id') == 'callFromContactName')
                    {
                        contact = $('#contactFromId').val();
                    }

                    if($('#'+id+'').attr('id') == 'callToContactName')
                    {
                        contact = $('#contactToId').val();
                    }

                    $.ajax(
                    {
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "php/myurl.php",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: 'callid='+$('#callid').val()+'&field='+$('#'+id+'').attr('id')+'&value='+encodeURIComponent($('#tooltipForm input').val())+'&contact='+contact,
                        success: function(j) 
                        {
                            return true;
                        },
                        error: function()
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                    });

                    return false;
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it seems to be working now. However, I see that the dynamic portion is not working for example the content in the form where I was setting the input value via $(this) and now that will not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Before you make the qtip call, check out the `$this=$(this)`  then you can use `$this.text()` in the form.. Did you try that?  http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/PqyFj/1/

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought that the $(this) of jquery would still be referring to the correct object, guess not. Thanks!

Comment: it still works the same however your context has changed.  When you are inside the plugin `$(this)` becomes something else that is related to the plugin.  I learn more by answering questions about plugins than anything else!  Thanks for the award.

Comment: Here is a question. If I am using these qtips on <a> items that are in a dialog which are being fed from the server, then I have to put the instantiation code for the qtips in the dialog code dont I? Right now when they go through, the $this.text() is empty because the data has not yet been fed from the server.

Comment: There are two ways to do it.. You can make your ajax call first and in the success callback you add your qtip (now you have the data) OR you can modify the `render` event and do it there..  Here is an example of the latter: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/content/translation

Comment: ah ha, so I did it on the succcess of the ajax call. Seemed simpler than to do another ajax call on the tooltip click. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: And lastly you could set the content in the show event.   http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/PqyFj/2/  Here is a mockup..