# jquery form in qtip not submitting with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, qtip2

I am having a problem getting this ajax form to submit within qtip ... It does submit but it ignores the e.PreventDefault() and just loads the in browser. Additionally it doesn't disable the submit button so it's like the code isn't even being called. I tried running it in the success: function and events: ... any help in this matter would be greatly appreciate.

JS:

```
    var editgallerysubmit    = $("#EditGallerySubmit");
var editgalleryform      = $("#EditGalleryForm");
var editgalleryresults   = $('#EditGalleryResults');

//Edit Gallery Form


//Edit Form When Hovering Over Gallery Name
$('.EditGallery').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('.EditGallery').each(function()
{


    $(this).qtip({
        content:  {
            text: "Loading...",
            ajax: {
                url:$(this).attr('href'),
                type: "GET",
                success: function(data, status) {   
                this.set('content.text', data);

                }                
            }
        },
        hide: {
            fixed: true,
            delay: 100
        },
        events: {
            render: function(event, api) {
                editgalleryform.bind('submit', function(e) {

                        $.ajax({
                            url: editgalleryform.attr('action'),
                            data: editgalleryform.serialize(),
                            type: 'post',
                            success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {

                            },
                            beforeSend: function() { editgallerysubmit.attr('disabled', ''); },
                            complete: function() { editgallerysubmit.removeAttr('disabled'); }
                        });

                        e.preventDefault();
                });
            }
        },
        style: 'wiki'
    });
    $(this).qtip('click', true);
});
```

PHP:

```
    $MemberGalleriesQuery = $bapcity->query("SELECT * FROM CroMemberRetailGalleries WHERE UserID='".$_SESSION['user_id']."' ORDER BY GalleryID DESC");
            $MemberGalleriesCount = $MemberGalleriesQuery->num_rows;

            if ( $MemberGalleriesCount ) 
            {
                $BaseHeight = 150;
                $GalleriesBoxHeight = $BaseHeight + ( 20 * $MemberGalleriesCount );
                echo '
                <div id="ManageGalleries" style="height: '.$GalleriesBoxHeight.'px" align="center">
                <div id="ManageGalleriesHeader">Manage Galleries</font></div><br><br>
                <font color="#000000"><b>Click Gallery To Edit</b></font><br><br>
                ';

                while($GalleryData = $MemberGalleriesQuery->fetch_assoc())
                {
                    echo '>> <b><a class="EditGallery" href="Crowork.Backend/Crowork.EditGallery.php?gallerykey='.$GalleryData['GalleryID'].'">'.$GalleryData['GalleryName'].'</a></b> <<<br>';
                }

                echo '<br><br></div>';
            }
            $MemberGalleriesQuery->free();
```

THE FORM PHP FILE:

```
    <form id="EditGalleryForm" action="Crowork.Backend/Crowork.EditGallery.php?action=DoEditGallery&gallerykey=<?php echo $GalleryData['GalleryID']?>" method="post">
    <table border="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center"><font size="-1"><b>NOTE:</b> Letters & Numbers Only</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="GalleryName" size="30" value="<?php echo $GalleryData['GalleryName']?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" colspan="2">
            <input type="hidden" name="OriginalGalleryName" value="<?php echo $GalleryData['GalleryName']?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="GalleryID" value="<?php echo $GalleryData['GalleryID'] ?>">
            <input id="EditGallerySubmit" type="submit" name="EditGallery" value="Edit Gallery">
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

ALL THE JAVASCRIPT CODE WORKS EXCEPT THIS PART THAT HANDLES SUBMISSION OF THE FORM.

```
    editgalleryform.bind('submit', function(e) {

                    $.ajax({
                        url: editgalleryform.attr('action'),
                        data: editgalleryform.serialize(),
                        type: 'post',
                        success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {

                        },
                        beforeSend: function() { editgallerysubmit.attr('disabled', ''); },
                        complete: function() { editgallerysubmit.removeAttr('disabled'); }
                    });

                    e.preventDefault();
            });
```

Comment: similar question with a possible answer: [stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10915266/qtip2-click-event-not-working-on-first-click)

Comment: yjs, I do thank you for taking your time in this matter, i reviewed that question you sent me and i was not successful in finding the solution i am looking for. In my case it's like events: isn't even working as i added 2 alerts as requested by: rohan and they didn't not pop up.

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind click event on submit button like,

```
editgallerysubmit.click(function() {
   $.ajax({ /** You ajax code */ });
   return false;// to prevent page reload                       
});
```

If your `form` is dynamically created then you need to use bind click event like,

```
// var editgallerysubmit will not work here bcoz it is dynamically created and your js rendered previously
$('#EditGallerySubmit').click(function() {
   $.ajax({ /** You ajax code */ });
   return false;// to prevent page reload                       
});
```

Comment: Hi Rohan, Thank you for your time in this matter. I did modify the code as you stated but i get the same effect sir.

Comment: add an alert in click event as well as in render function

Comment: Rohan, i added the 2 alerts and neither one of them came up.

Comment: So, check in console for any errors and check your settings why the render event is not working.

Comment: Yes sir i have done so and firebug reports no errors in the console.

Comment: OK so i took on of the alerts outside of $("#EditGallerySubmit").bind('click', function() { and it works. So the problem lies within the .bind

Comment: You see i get the form and it returns from a file Crowork.Backend/Crowork.EditGallery.php then in the success: it gets put in the tooltip. So the form that gets put in the tool tip i need to have it submit via ajax rather than the standard browser submission.